# Labels not appearing in python bokeh bar plot with groups

Tags: python, bokeh

I want to add labels with the values above the bars like here: [How to add data labels to a bar chart in Bokeh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401481/how-to-add-data-labels-to-a-bar-chart-in-bokeh) but don't know how to do it. My code looks different then other examples, the code is working but maybe it is not the right way.

My code:

```
from bokeh.io import export_png
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral5
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.sampledata.autompg import autompg_clean as df
from bokeh.transform import factor_cmap
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, ranges, LabelSet, Label
import pandas as pd

d = {'lvl': ["lvl1", "lvl2", "lvl2", "lvl3"],
   'feature': ["test1", "test2","test3","test4"],
     'count': ["5", "20","8", "90"]}
dfn = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
sourceframe = ColumnDataSource(data=dfn)

groupn = dfn.groupby(by=['lvl', 'feature'])
index_cmapn = factor_cmap('lvl_feature', palette=Spectral5, factors=sorted(dfn.lvl.unique()), end=1)


pn = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=300, title="Count",x_range=groupn, toolbar_location=None)

labels = LabelSet(x='feature', y='count', text='count', level='glyph',x_offset=0, y_offset=5, source=sourceframe, render_mode='canvas',)


pn.vbar(x='lvl_feature', top="count_top" ,width=1, source=groupn,line_color="white", fill_color=index_cmapn, )

pn.y_range.start = 0
pn.x_range.range_padding = 0.05
pn.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
pn.xaxis.axis_label = "levels"
pn.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 1.2
pn.outline_line_color = None
pn.add_layout(labels)
export_png(pn, filename="color.png")
```

I think it has something to do with my `dfn.groupby(by=['lvl', 'feature'])` and the (probably wrong) `sourceframe = ColumnDataSource(data=dfn)`.

The plot at this moment:
[image]

Comment: How is your code different from the linked example? You have a data source, you call `vbar` - that's all you need. Just create a `LabelSet` using the correct values and add it to the plot.

Comment: Because I don't use ```ColumnDataSource``` to create the plot. But this is needed for the labels. I create a ```LabelSet``` now but the labels do not appear in the plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the groups names in the initial dictionary like this:

```
d = {'lvl': ["lvl1", "lvl2", "lvl2", "lvl3"],
     'feature': ["test1", "test2","test3","test4"],
     'count': ["5", "20","8", "90"],
     'groups': [('lvl1', 'test1'), ('lvl2', 'test2'), ('lvl2', 'test3'), ('lvl3', 'test4')]}
```

And then call LabelSet using as x values the groups.

```
labels = LabelSet(x='groups', y='count', text='count', level='glyph',x_offset=20, y_offset=0, source=sourceframe, render_mode='canvas',)
```

In this way the labels appear. Note that I played a bit with the offset to check if that was the problem, you can fix that manually.

[image]

Comment: You sir are amazing. I assume this works because ```('lvl1', 'test1')``` is matching with ```groupn = dfn.groupby(by=['lvl', 'feature'])```

Comment: yes exactly, I actually iterated through groupn to get the groups names.